# css horizontal scroll with ul li tags + bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, scroll, scrollbar

I'm trying to horizontal scroll using bootstrap, but I'm not able to get it to scroll horizontally. My `li` tags just doesn't wrap the way it should (it's wrapping normally).

HTML:

```
<div class="container suggest">
  <ul class="thumbnails bsuggest" >
    <li class="span2">
     text goes here
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bsuggest
{
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    height:250px;
    white-space:nowrap !important;
    width:100%;
}
.bsuggest li
{
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    *dsplay:inline;/* For IE7*/
    *zoom:1;/* For IE7*/
    white-space:normal;
}
.suggest
{
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:95px;
}
```

I think I've done what its supposed to but it's not giving me what I need

Comment: Can you give any examples of what you are trying to achieve? You want the `li` to not wrap and that's it?

Comment: @DigTheDoug i'd like my `li` not to wrap, so if i have multiple `li` tags, it will go past my screen for horizontal scroll

Comment: Sorry, you're going to have to give a more concrete example. Plugging that code into jsfiddle looks to behave how you expect: the list is horizontally aligned and is only constricted horizontally by the outer page element.